# Переключение текущей группы процессов

Tags: linux, c, fork

Есть код, который вызывает форк, переключает текущую группу терминала на новую группу, лидером которой является процесс после форк, основной процесс после этого просто ждет завершения порожденного.

После определенных действий в новом процессе происходит переключение текущей группы терминала на прежнюю, но как быть если новый процесс завершился из-за сигнала? Он не доходит до строчки кода с переключением группы на прежнюю, в итоге получается что основной процесс теперь остался фоновым.

Использую для этого tcsetpgrp.

Вопрос проще: как фоновый процесс сделать текущим, без участия активного процесса (Если активный, допустим, завершился).

UPD (code):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int32_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
                execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
                perror("cat");
                fflush(stderr);
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        setpgid(pid, pid);
        tcsetpgrp(0, pid);
        wait(NULL);
        tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid())); // не работает?
        int32_t c = 0;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != 'g');
        return 0;
}
```

Пример запуска кода, то есть запустился "cat", ввел asd, программа тоже выдает asd, жму ctrl+c, "cat" завершился и всё, основной процесс остался как фоновый.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Вам точно не будет достаточно демонизировать процесс при помощи условного systemd? Что вы пишете?

Comment: @Sheridan, просто пытаюсь переключить текущую группу, если сигналом завершился переключающий процесс и он не успел этого сделать)

Comment: @Sheridan, у меня в голове 2 варианта: через обработку сигнала это делать, либо в фоновом процессе создавать новую связку дескрипторов с терминалом и завершать основной процесс аварийно, исходя из данных от wait. Может есть другой способ?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы такое пишете что вам приходится жонглировать процессами вот так

Comment: @Sheridan, это всё нужно мне для написания аналога Shell'a. Идет ввод, лексический анализ и запуск программ в отдельных процессах. После запуска программы мне нужно делать её группу текущей для терминала, что бы тот же ctrl+c ей отправить, а не основной программе, потом сделать основную группу как текущую снова. В основной программе вообще отключен каноничный режим, эхо и прочее.

Comment: Ох, я такое писать ещо не пробовал, соррян, не помогу...

Comment: [setpgid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpgrp) не подходит?

Comment: М.б. в [Job Control](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_27.html) найдете что-то полезное

Comment: @avp, нашел, Foreground and Background, в принципе, я так и делаю, как там описано. Делаю форк, переключаю текущую группу, запустил "cat", завершаю "cat" ctrl+c, в основном процессе дальше идет wait(NULL), после идет tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid())). Ииии... Мой процесс (основной) становится остановленным, то есть stopped, почему-то... Так же и "ls" если запустить, он отработает, завершится и основной процесс stopped. Я обновлю вопрос, добавлю код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос найден в более четком прочтении man tcsetpgrp...

"If tcsetpgrp() is called by a member of a background process group in its session, and the calling process is not blocking or ignoring SIGTTOU, a SIGTTOU signal is sent to all members of this background process group."

Почему он приходит при смене текущей группы? Ищу полное описание сигнала и нахожу:

Сигнал SIGTTOU приходит группе фоновых процессов при попытке **вывода на терминал или при попытке смены настроек** (так я перевел для себя фразу "...**to write to the terminal or set its modes**..."), **"...set its modes..."** - это включает так же и попытку смены текущей группы (так думаю я, так видимо и есть). Полное описание из gnu.org:

"This is similar to SIGTTIN, but is generated when a process in a background job attempts to write to the terminal or set its modes. Again, the default action is to stop the process. SIGTTOU is only generated for an attempt to write to the terminal if the TOSTOP output mode is set; see Output Modes.".

Вот код, который не допустит остановку основного процесса:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int32_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
                execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
                perror("cat");
                fflush(stderr);
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        setpgid(pid, pid);
        tcsetpgrp(0, pid);
        wait(NULL);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN); // это - решение проблемы, игнорирование сигнала.
        tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid()));
        int32_t c = 0;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != 'g');
        return 0;
}
```

Либо делать вызов signal() в начале программы, а в новом процессе вызывать signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL). Как-то так. Спасибо за помощь, всё, как обычно, элементарно ))

Comment: Молодец, сам нашел. Я уже хотел ответить на коммент о сигнале, а  потом увидел этот ответ

Comment: @avp, хех ) Неочевидная вещь на самом деле. А когда узнаешь о ней - очевидная ))

Answer (score 0):

> основной процесс после этого просто ждет завершения порожденного

как дождется что тот процесс упал - пусть сам переключит группу

Comment: pid = fork(); setpgid(pid, pid); tcsetpgrp(0, pid); wait(NULL); tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid())); - это не работает, в этом то и беда... То есть я дождался завершения, и после wait смена текущей группы не срабатывает, мне просто консоль линукса выдает что мой основной процесс остановлен...

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил код.